# Displaying various row-/column-wise permutations of matrix

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I have a data matrix that consists of 5 rows and 5 columns and I'm looking for a way to display possible combinations that the values within the table can be rearranged. Is there a function that can do this? I tried using combn() but that just returned a single column of 30 values that are in the same order as the matrix.

```
 Data <- matrix(c(1:25),nrow=5,ncol=5)
 Data
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

Comment: Please rephrase this to address a *specific* question, and try to include any data or code related to your problem.

Comment: Unless you make some effort at implementing this, it is a ***Give me teh codez***-type post and is likely to be closed for lack of effort.

Comment: I added the code to show what I'm working with. I hope this helps

Comment: I guess you are looking for permutations. You do realize that for 25 unique values this number is huge and almost endless with regard to computation time? That would be `1.551121e+25` unique sets of numbers

Comment: Is there possibly a way to return one set of 25 permutated values then?

Comment: What do you mean? Try `library(gtools) ; permutations(4, 4, 1:4)` for example, for all permutations of `1:4`

Comment: I would like another matrix with the same values, but just rearranged.

Comment: Okay great. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) in order to understand what you are trying to do. You are at 25

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think OP wants to visualize this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you one possible instance of the permuted row values:

```
> apply(Data,1,sample)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   21   17    8   19   15
[2,]   11   12   18   14   20
[3,]    6   22   23   24   10
[4,]   16    2    3    9    5
[5,]    1    7   13    4   25
```

Notice that it is probably the transpose of the matrix you wanted, since `apply` always returns its results in column-major order, so to get what was probably expected, you would do this:

```
 t( apply(Data,1,sample) )  
 # a different row permutation since no set.seed()

> t( apply(Data,1,sample) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    6    1   21   11   16
[2,]   12    7   22   17    2
[3,]   23   13    3    8   18
[4,]   14   19    9    4   24
[5,]   20   25   10   15    5
```

If you want to randomly permute the column values, then change the second apply argument to 2 and do not use `t()`.

Comment: Wow, that was the fastest accept in the history of SO